# Gridview in Listview is repeating the last gridview items for every line

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview

I'm trying to make a listview with for each row: a title and grid of items. With the below code I get a list of correct titles, but the gridView on each row is filled with the items of the last row.

The logging shows that every time getView is called it gets the correct items with the correct title. I suspect there is a shared reference, or I'm writing to the wrong row somewhere.

Similar questions are all problems with the recycling of views, which I'm doing right.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_my_listview, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.myGridView = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_gridview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    listItemDetails item = itemDetailsArrayList.get(position);
    holder.txt_name.setText(item.name);

    gridItemListAdapter gridArrayAdapter = new gridItemListAdapter(context, item.getGridItems());
    holder.myGridView.setAdapter(gridArrayAdapter);

    Util.Log(getClass().getName());
    Util.Log(cabinetId + " - " + cabinet.getCageList().size());
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: you are using the same adapter for all row. So when the last row get's updated, the value for all grid items are same as that...

Comment: @HourGlass That would explain it. But I make a new instance of gridItemListAdapter with the correct items every time getView is called. How is it then the same?

Comment: Can you just check your data , whether all the data are unique?

Comment: @NigamPatro Yes. One row has 1 item and the other 7, so they are very different. Now I only see both rows with the same 1 item. In the logging it clearly states that it the correct ID is matched with the correct number of items. So what happens is apparently it somehow sets the correct value for the gridview, and then overwrites it when it sets the next row.

Comment: Mean, the whole gridview?

Comment: @NigamPatro Its a gridview within a listview.

Comment: (I cannot reproduce the problem David, everything works great on my tests) I suspect a problem in your model with `item.getGridItems()`, which could return the last update. Try to not doing in method, but with `item.gridItems` (like you do to get item's name).

Comment: @Fllo Yessss. That was the problem.With item.griditems it works as expected. Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it's working now. Thanks to accept my answer, I hope I didn't made mistake about the structure of your object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comment above, the problem occurs when you get the item's `GridView` on `item.getGridItems()` at this line:

```
gridItemListAdapter gridArrayAdapter = new gridItemListAdapter(context, item.getGridItems());
```

The problem is not the adapter which has each single instance. The last row's dup happens because - I'll try to guess your structure, I didn't know but I saw the clue -, each time you call this method, you might use the same `array` and so the same values.
Thus, the last update for last row change every `GridItems` references in each adapter instances.

When I made my test to resolve this, I avoided to get it with an extra work in `getView()` in my adapters by calling an object treatment. I used an object's field which was already setted. So you have to do the same as you get item's name: `item.name` in order to get the gridview's items as follows:

```
gridItemListAdapter gridArrayAdapter = new gridItemListAdapter(context, item.gridItems);
```

And it should be like this in your `Item` object:

```
public ArrayList<Images> gridItems; // arraylist or whatever
...
public void setGridItems(ArrayList<Images> gridItems) { // set it when you set the name
    this.gridItems = gridItems;
}
```

Therefore, the `Item` object will have new `GridItems` for each instance.